# Node.js Sequelize forbid some paramaters in model.Update

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm making an API with `Express` and `Sequelize`

I want my user to be able to update some entries without having a defined number of params.

For example, if I have the following "Books" database table :

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| name | varchar |
| description | text |
| userId | int |

I have a `post` route to update the entry :

```
function(req, res)
{
    
    var screenUpdate = Book.update(req.body,
        {where: {id: req.body.id}})
        .then(function(){
            return res.status(201).json({
                "data": "ok"
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            return res.status(500).json({'error':"Impossible de modifier."}); 
        });
}
```

In this case, the user will put in the request the params that it need, for example `name, description` but it doesn't prevent it to add `id` or `userId` which could break the database.
How could I forbid those parameters from being updated by that request ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should limit or filter the `req.body`. Remove sensitive fields before passing them into the update function. One simple way is:

```js
function(req, res) {
  const { id, userId, ...safeFields } = req.body;
  const screenUpdate = Book
    .update(safeFields, { where: { id: req.body.id } })
    .then(() => res.status(201)
      .json({
        data: 'ok',
      }))
    .catch((err) => res.status(500)
      .json({ error: 'Impossible de modifier.' }));
},
```

As a safer option, define a white list of allowed fields:

```js
function(req, res) {
  // Field names that are allowed to edit
  const allowedFields = ['BookName', 'Author', 'Date'];

  // Extract values of allowed fields if presented in the body
  const safeFields = allowedFields
    .filter((x) => req.body[x] != null)
    .reduce((state, x) => ({ ...state, [x]: req.body[x] }), {});

  const screenUpdate = Book
    .update(safeFields, { where: { id: req.body.id } })
    .then(() => res.status(201).json({ data: 'ok' }))
    .catch((err) => res.status(500).json({ error: 'Impossible de modifier.' }));
},
```

If allowed fields are wider than banned ones, use a reverse approach:

```js
function(req, res) {
  // Field names that shouldn't update
  const blackList = ['id', 'userId'];

  // Make a copy of the body then remove banned fields
  const safeFields = { ...req.body };
  blackList.forEach((x) => delete safeFields[x]);

  const screenUpdate = Book
    .update(safeFields, { where: { id: req.body.id } })
    .then(() => res.status(201).json({ data: 'ok' }))
    .catch((err) => res.status(500).json({ error: 'Impossible de modifier.' }));
},
```

Comment: Thank you ! This make sense indeed, but I thought that Sequelize maybe had a built in method to prevent that